# Ubuntu 20.04 cannot go to suspend. X applications are closed after try to suspend

Tags: 20.04, suspend

I have a computer with Ubuntu 20.04. After installation of Ubuntu 20.04 suspend worked fine, but some time ago it stopped to work.

I press Suspend button in the menu, after that screen becomes black for a few seconds but fans continue rotation. After that screen turns on and I see a login screen. When I input the password, I see that all X applications were destroyed.

I tried different kernels, but result is the same.

`cat /proc/acpi/wakeup` command gives the next result:

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
PS2K      S3    *enabled   pnp:00:03
PS2M      S3    *disabled  pnp:00:04
IP2P      S3    *disabled
XHCI      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
EHC1      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
EHC2      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0
RP01      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
RP02      S4    *disabled
RP03      S4    *disabled
RP04      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.3
RTLG      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:06:00.0
RP05      S4    *disabled
RP06      S4    *disabled
RP07      S4    *disabled
RP08      S4    *disabled
RTLA      S4    *disabled
BR1A      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:01.0
BR1B      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:01.1
BR2A      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:02.0
BR2B      S4    *disabled
BR2C      S4    *disabled
BR2D      S4    *disabled
BR3A      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:03.0
BR3B      S4    *disabled
BR3C      S4    *disabled
BR3D      S4    *disabled
QRP0      S4    *disabled
QR1A      S4    *disabled
QR1B      S4    *disabled
QR2A      S4    *disabled
QR2B      S4    *disabled
QR2C      S4    *disabled
QR2D      S4    *disabled
QR3A      S4    *disabled
QR3B      S4    *disabled
QR3C      S4    *disabled
QR3D      S4    *disabled
RRP0      S4    *disabled
RR1A      S4    *disabled
RR1B      S4    *disabled
RR2A      S4    *disabled
RR2B      S4    *disabled
RR2C      S4    *disabled
RR2D      S4    *disabled
RR3A      S4    *disabled
RR3B      S4    *disabled
RR3C      S4    *disabled
RR3D      S4    *disabled
SRP0      S4    *disabled
SR1A      S4    *disabled
SR1B      S4    *disabled
SR2A      S4    *disabled
SR2B      S4    *disabled
SR2C      S4    *disabled
SR2D      S4    *disabled
SR3A      S4    *disabled
SR3B      S4    *disabled
SR3C      S4    *disabled
SR3D      S4    *disabled
```

`journalctl -b | grep suspend` command shows next errors:

````
feb 05 21:00:17 user-pc gsd-power[1888]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
feb 05 21:00:17 user-pc gsd-power[2610]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
feb 05 21:00:17 user-pc gsd-media-keys[2607]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
feb 05 21:00:17 user-pc gsd-media-keys[1874]: Unable to inhibit suspend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying```

I tried to install Unity desktop instead of Gnome but result is the same except it doesn't kill X applications.

In my ```/var/log/syslog``` I see the next troubles connected with suspend:

```Feb  8 21:39:04 user-pc ModemManager[1208]: <warn>  [sleep-monitor] inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Feb  8 21:39:04 user-pc upowerd[1420]: Could not acquire inhibitor lock: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Feb  8 21:39:04 user-pc systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb  8 21:39:04 user-pc systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
````

pm-suspend suspends normally but sometimes fails to wake up.

Could you help me?

Comment: I doubt the applications were destroyed maybe closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My PC has AMD 6450 gpu and Nvidia Tesla K20m gpu. After I completely reinstalled both gpu drivers to proprietary ones issue disappeared.